# Zend Autoloader not loading Zend classes

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using the Zend Framework 2.0 to autoload Zend classes in my application, independent of an MVC framework.

The location of the zend framework, is C:/wamp/library/zendframework/library (contains Zend/Soap etc.)

Below is my code:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';

$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
'Zend' => 'c:/wamp/library/zendframework/library'));

$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Zend', 'c:/wamp/library/zendframework/library');
$loader->register();



$auto = new Zend/Soap/Server(null,null);
$auto->setClass('services');
$auto->handle();
```

I'm trying to load the Zend/Soap/Server, but I keep getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend' not found in C:\wamp\www\Zend_soap\server.php on line 42
```

whereby on line 42:

```
$auto = new Zend/Soap/Server(null,null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very close, I think;
If your ZF2 installation is on the php include_path you should only need 3 lines of code and 4 if it;s not on the include_path.

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';

//if ZF2 is on php include_path set autoregister_zf to true else false
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
//Zend would be a vendor prefix not namespace, however a namespace may work just fine
//$loader->registerNamespace('Zend', 'c:/wamp/library/zendframework/library');
//if ZF2 is not on php include path and needs to be registered as a vendor
//$loader->registerPrefix('Zend', 'c:/wamp/library/zendframework/library');
$loader->register();
```

> **autoregister_zf**: An boolean value indicating that the class should
>   register the *“Zend”* namespace to the directory above where its own
>   classfile is located on the filesystem.

Good Luck! I hope this helped.